# Help in trying to understand a proof : Lebesgue outer measure as infimum of a Lebesgue Measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need help in trying to understand this proof (at the beginning of page 23, page 16 of the pdf) : [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf#page26](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf#page26)

I dont understand this part : Let $S_i$ be an rectangle whose interior ${S_i}^◦$ contains $R_i$ such that
$μ(S_i) ≤ μ(R_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$

If the interior of the rectangle S contains the rectangle R, how its possible that the measure of R is bigger or equal than the measure of S? I am misunderstanding something here?

Thanks.

Edit : Now I realize, the union of $S_i$ is bigger than the union of $R_i$, but each $S_i$ is less or equal than each $R_i$, is that correct?

Comment: Can you have a title reflecting the topic you're trying to understand? This is not the case currently. Thanks. On tip of that, the inequality you write doesn't contain a contradiction. There is the second term in RHS!

Comment: $μ(S_i) ≤ μ(R_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$ does not imply that $μ(S_i) ≤ μ(R_i)$.  Actually  $μ(S_i)>μ(R_i)$, but the difference is "small"  $μ(S_i) -μ(R_i) <\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$

Comment: @RobertZ Oh I see. I forget to consider the epsilon part. Thanks!